# How can i hide first empty column and headings row in a TKINTER TREEVIEW?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I need to hide first empty column and headings row in a tkinter treeview using python. (as you know, 'show=headings' hides first empty column but shows headings, 'show=tree' hides headings but shows headings)

Is there a way to hide both?

Comment: Did you try `show=""`?

Comment: From the documentation, show is _"A list containing zero or more of the following values, specifying which elements of the tree to display."_

Comment: simple answer: `"#0", width=0, stretch="no"' in your column

Comment: thx everybody i'm using show='', it works good too